# Is there anyone whose first name is the same as their middle name?

Tags: history, names

For example, is there anyone with a full name like "David David Smith", where David is the first name and David is also the middle name? Also, I am wondering if there is anyone with a first and middle name that are pronounced exactly the same, but are spelled differently? For example: "Kaitlin Catelynn Johnson".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there aren't any rules in the English language about what kind of names people can have.

Comment: Some countries have (legal) rules about how a parent can name a child when registering the birth. The UK has only one, that the name must not be "offensive". The refusal of a name by a registrar can be appealed in court. A judge has ruled that parents could not legally name their child "Cyanide", as the name might cause the child harm. The harm, I think, would be mockery and teasing in school and later. New Zealand frowns upon names that are official titles, Judge, Captain, etc. Denmark, Spain, Germany and Argentina publish lists of ‘acceptable’ names that parents must choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of agree with sumelic's comment, but for your edification:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_T._Riley

Comment: And who could forget [Run Run Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_Run_Shaw)?

Comment: And although technically the man's first and middle names were "Charles" and "Edward," everyone knew him as [Cow Cow Davenport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_Cow_Davenport).

Comment: @SvenYargs of course not his actual middle name, just a transcription of "Shao Renleng" in the Ningbo Dialect

Comment: I would draw the line at [Boom Boom Geoffrion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Geoffrion), however.

Comment: In John Cale's song "Paris 1919", on the album of the same name: _The Continent's just fallen in disgrace/William William William Rogers put it in its place_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The real William P. Rogers had only one "William" in his name. He was secretary of state under Richard Nixon from 1969 to 1973. Cale's allusion, I believe is to a dismissive comment about Europe that Rogers made on the subject of Great Powers, though I don't remember the details.On the subject of duplicate names, there was a joke after the first Pope John Paul (who had named himself after his two most recent predecessors, John and Paul) died that the next pope was considering naming himself after his _three_ most recent predecessors, calling himself "Pope John Paul John Paul."